# removing the empty gray space in datagrid in c#

Tags: c#

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/260c1f6706.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/260c1f6706.jpg)

how do i remove the empty space i.e. i want the datagrid to automatically resize itself depending upon the no. of rows. i know for columns we can do that by using fill value in AutoSizeColumnMode, but there is no fill value for AutoSizeRowsMode.

Comment: That's "cognitively disabled" highlight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit of a hack but you may try this:

```
dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
```

Btw this has been [reported as a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=116071).

Comment: This works, but then you still have the border. Any idea how to remove that?

Answer (score 11):

It can be done, you'd have to adjust the ClientSize when a row is added or removed.  However, it doesn't hide the background completely once the vertical scrollbar appears and the grid height is not a divisble by the row height.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class AutoSizeGrid : DataGridView {
  private int gridHeight;
  private bool resizing;
  protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
    if (!resizing) gridHeight = this.ClientSize.Height;
    base.OnClientSizeChanged(e);
  }
  protected override void OnRowsAdded(DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
    setGridHeight();
    base.OnRowsAdded(e);
  }
  protected override void OnRowsRemoved(DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e) {
    setGridHeight();
    base.OnRowsRemoved(e);
  }
  protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(setGridHeight));
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
  }
  private void setGridHeight() {
    if (this.DesignMode || this.RowCount > 99) return;
    int height = this.ColumnHeadersHeight + 2;
    if (this.HorizontalScrollBar.Visible) height += SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight;
    for (int row = 0; row < this.RowCount; ++row) {
      height = Math.Min(gridHeight, height + this.Rows[row].Height);
      if (height >= gridHeight) break;
    }
    resizing = true;
    this.ClientSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width, height);
    resizing = false;
    if (height < gridHeight && this.RowCount > 0) this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: thx for your effort but i got rid of that space by using the method suggested above.

Comment: I found some issue in my tests, look: http://prnt.sc/b3rf7g can I remove the little gray row too? depending on the data, the left handed corner has a big graw area: http://prnt.sc/b3rft4 How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Set the `MaxHeight` property of the datagrid. e.g `MaxHeight="150"`

In my case I have removed the space what you have shown in the above grid with red boarder.