# DataGridView variable formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with data I extract from `SQL Server`.
I never know how many records i'll have in it so I need the grid to be variable to the number of rows extracted.

Exemple :

[image]

- Picture 1 : What I have right now. 1 row was extracted so I have a big dark gray space where the could have been data.
- Picture 2 : What I want to have with only 1 row extracted. The grid resizes automaticly depending on the number of rows.
- Picture 3 : What I would like to have with many rows.

Also, I would like to remove the empty row that is always added too, adding a new row won't be an option.

Is that possible ?

Comment: @Nathan if you take the time to read the full question and NOT just the end, you'll see that this isn't the same question..at all

Comment: @Nathan Np just pointing that out so I can get the answer i'm looking for,

Comment: Set AllowUserToAddRows=False to get rid of the empty row at the bottom (that's there to allow the user to add a new row).

Comment: @C-PoundGuru thanks that did the job for that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `DataSet.Datatable.Rows.Count` this will tell you the total rows returned from your Sql Server

**Update this cannot be achieved by using the any properties of the DataGridView Control**

Comment: What do I do with number ofr rows when I get them ? How can I tell that if I have 6 rows show me only 6 rows not 6 rows + a big gray space ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk looks like this question have been asked before and their is no solution on the control itself, please look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162756/datagridview-remove-unused-space

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll stop looking for a way to do it then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `AutoSizeColumns` properties:

```
datagridview.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
datagridview.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
```

Assuming you're filling the grid from a `DataSet`, you can use this to prevent empty rows from being added:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[0].ToString()))
      {
            //add row
      }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a DataTable as a DataSource. I changed both Porperties but I still get the big grey space...

Comment: Where did you place the code to set those properties? You will get a gray area at the bottom of the grid until your query returns enough results to fill it... Otherwise you could just adjust it's height?

Comment: Yes I know that's why i'm asking this question. Is there a way NOT to wait for enough rows and make the Height Variable instead.. 
I didn't code it I changed those properties in the designer property pannel