# By using c# , how can I make disappear the grey unnecessary zone in my datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the screenshot of the datagridView, By using c# , how can I make disappear the grey unnecessary zone in my datagridview?
[image]

Comment: Make your datagridview fittowindow.

Comment: Which grey zone? you need to be more specific. Please add a circle to the image and update it.

Comment: is this really asp.net? seems like a winforms component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DatagridView: Remove unused space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162756/datagridview-remove-unused-space)

Comment: my bad, it's a winform component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162756/datagridview-remove-unused-space).

It seems though that this person had the exact same problem as you in some aspect and seemingly got rid of it by means of the top rated answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you find a question is a duplicate don't answer it, mark it as a duplicate instead.

Comment: On the plus side, this question has a working screenshot. The other one does not (broken link).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Options.

### Option 1:

Add this line to your `Form_Load` Event:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

### Option 2:

Change the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` property in `Datagridview` to `Fill`

[image]