# remove gray space from DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, whitespace

I am a vb.net developer. I am developing a chat application. I have added a Datagridview in my form. When i add row in datagridview programmatically, sometimes its shows me grayspace after the last row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/riGuH.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6ao1.png

See the above image and please give me solution.

Comment: Can you show us the significant part of your code?

Comment: I have set properties of datagridview
AllowUserToAddRows = false
AllowUserToDeleteRows = false
AllowUserToResizeColumns = false
AllowUserToResizeRows = false
AutoSizeRowsMode = AllCells
BorderStyle = None
ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = AutoSize
ColumnHeadersVisible = false
Dock = Fill
RowHeaderVisible = False

then just assign the datatable to datasource

Comment: I got Extra spaces after last row and also Scroll is there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing the empty gray space in datagrid in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122985/removing-the-empty-gray-space-in-datagrid-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Its just hide the gray color. but actually as i said, i am working on Chat Application. so i have a Textbox below grid. and it also shows unnecessary space ans scroll. so its looking too bad

Comment: see this URL

http://i.stack.imgur.com/o6ao1.png