# How to fill datagridview grayed area using empty rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to know how to fill empty rows in datagridview's rest of grayed area, after datagridview has bind the data. Anyone have a simple method for this please comment here.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suggest setting the Backcolor to the cell backcolor instead so the users won't click around and select ghost cells..

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122985/removing-the-empty-gray-space-in-datagrid-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `Rows` to a `DataGridView` to fill up the space has a number of problems:

- The most obvious is that **you can't** add them as your DGV is `DataBound`. So you would have to add rows to your `DataSource`. Which is not really nice.
- Less obvious: The rows would not only **look** like rows, they would also **be** real rows and **behave** like real rows i.e. be clickable, selectable etc.. This is confusing for users even if you prevent editing it will still invite interactions that are not really plausible.
- Finally: You would still have to take care of the grey areas to the right, at least if there is some or if the users can resize columns.

Here is what I suggest doing instead:

To make the grey area look unobtrusive simply set the `DataGridView`'s `BackColor` to the color of the normal cells:

```
 yourDGV.BackgroundColor = yourDGV.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background color to transparent or the same color as your form would be a good thing, but if you don't want to do that, you'll have to create a custom datagridview for that. You should probably check this [Thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d39e565e-cf33-45b9-993c-99d39813fd15/datagridview-filling-rest-of-rows-with-empty-lines?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 0):

Create your Custom `DataGridView`, I've tested it works kind of glitchy for me on other `AutoSizeColumnsMode`, so set it to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;`, but anyway:

```
public class GridLineDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        int rowHeight = this.RowTemplate.Height;

        int h = this.ColumnHeadersHeight + rowHeight * this.RowCount;
        int imgWidth = this.Width - 2;
        Rectangle rFrame = new Rectangle(0, 0, imgWidth, rowHeight);
        Rectangle rFill = new Rectangle(1, 1, imgWidth - 2, rowHeight);
        Rectangle rowHeader = new Rectangle(2, 2, this.RowHeadersWidth - 3, rowHeight);

        Pen pen = new Pen(this.GridColor, 1);

        Bitmap rowImg = new Bitmap(imgWidth, rowHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rowImg);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rFrame);
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor), rFill);
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor), rowHeader);

        Bitmap rowImgAAlternative = rowImg.Clone() as Bitmap;
        Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(rowImgAAlternative);
        rFill.X += this.RowHeadersWidth - 1;
        g2.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor), rFill);

        int w = this.RowHeadersWidth - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < this.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(w, 0), new Point(w, rowHeight));
            g2.DrawLine(pen, new Point(w, 0), new Point(w, rowHeight));
            w += this.Columns[j].Width;
        }

        int loop = (this.Height - h) / rowHeight;
        for (int j = 0; j < loop + 1; j++)
        {
            int index = this.RowCount + j;
            if (index % 2 == 0)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(rowImg, 1, h + j * rowHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(rowImgAAlternative, 1, h + j * rowHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

change your `private DataGridView dataGridView;` to `private GridLineDataGridView dataGridView;`